# Different paths between Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, ubuntu, path

I use Windows and Ubuntu to code with Eclipse, also I have a big folder with a lot of libraries inside it so i can choose the library i want and add it to my project...
But windows and linux (Ubuntu) doesnt uses the same paths for the libraries, i add a library on windows and on ubuntu it doesnt work because ubuntu cant find G:/Programation/Libraries, if i want to add a library on ubuntu, it is /media/Media1/Programation/Libraries...
I have searched here a little bit for this, but i dont understand how that works, also I cant move my libraries to the SDK Java path, i need to move the java stuff in various computers...
Also idk how variables works on eclipse... Idk how to add a lib of a variable
Help is apreciatted. Note that im on Java 7 and Eclipse Luna, Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04
Also i cant move the libraries folder to the project lib folder...
Also why file structure is something like this:
-G:/
 -Programation
  -Workspaces
   -Bukkit
    -**FIRST WORKSPACE**
   -Java
    -**SECOND WORKSPACE**
   -BungeeCord
    -**THIRD WORKSPACE**
  -Libraries
   -**ALL THE LIBRARIES**

Comment: i don't know eclipse very well, but isn't it possible to define relative-paths when adding new libraries? this is possible in netbeans. in netbeans you can choose between relative path and absolute path, when adding libs.

Comment: Are you using _the same_ workspace for both Windows and Ubuntu, or just the same projects in _different_ workspaces? If the latter is the case, you can use class path variables.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I honestly don't know how to fix the path issue, but because you mention you're using Eclipse I assume we're talking about Java Libraries. I can suggest one thing: use Maven for dependencies. 
You can easily configure the needed libraries for your project without having to mess around with adding them manually to you build path.

This should help you getting started with Maven:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E

Comment: This should probably be posted as a comment rather than an answer, considering your suggestion does not really answer the user's question.

Answer (score 3):

Path "/media/Media1/Programation/Libraries..." tells me your shared partition is not properly mounted from Ubuntu.
You should install ntfs-configuration tool from Ubuntu Software center and it will mount all your partitions in a proper read/write mode.
After that, you will be able to specify paths which will stay consistent.